# MySQL = AND(CASE.. ELSE 1=1) ..........meaning

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with the AND portion of the MySQL statement below, what does it mean?

```
SELECT account_names
FROM Accounts
WHERE id NOT IN(1, 2, 3)
AND (CASE
    WHEN inviteCode IS NOT NULL THEN inviteCode <> 'xxxYYY'
    ELSE 1=1
    END);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT account_names
FROM Accounts
WHERE
    id NOT IN (1, 2, 3) AND
    (inviteCode <> 'xxxYYY' OR inviteCode IS NULL);
```

The logic your `CASE` expression uses is that the invite code can't be `xxxYYY` if not `NULL`.  Note carefully that the following logical expression will evaluate to false when appearing in a `WHERE` clause:

```
NULL <> 'xxxYYY'
```

Hence, we need a separate condition in the `WHERE` clause to also allow a record with a `NULL` invite code.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I am a new user here. I have a few more questions below.

Comment: What are the questions?

Comment: I posted it below, not sure how to format "Add Comment" text.

Comment: HI TIm, did you see my follow up question on this post?  It is written as an "Answer to my question" below.

Answer (score 0):

Here in query formed for get `account_names` which have id not (1,2,3) and `inviteCode` not `xxxYYY'` or `inviteCode` is `null`

so

if `inviteCode` is not null then `inviteCode <> 'xxxYYY'` will check other vise it return `1=1` means `true` because in result `null` `inviteCode` is also valid

Answer (score 0):

So is my interpretation correct?

**WHEN inviteCode IS NOT NULL THEN inviteCode <> 'xxxYYY'**

- If the inviteCode is not NULL then return records which don't have an inviteCode of xxxYYY

**ELSE 1=1**

- yes, return records where inviteCode is NULL

Is there a reason why the original author structured the code this way?

Can something like this be written as well?

```
AND(
(id NOT IN (1, 2, 3) AND inviteCode <> 'xxxYYY') OR
(id NOT IN (1, 2, 3) AND inviteCode IS NULL)
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Anyone care to answer my follow up question? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, your final version is correct, but it can be simplified to `id NOT IN (1, 2, 3) AND (inviteCode <> 'xxxYYY' OR inviteCode IS NULL)`, which is what my answer says.